# In android, how do I pass information from one activity (Dialog) to another?

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut

I have a dialog which opens up to showall installed apps which are launchable. I display them in a gridview, and upon GridItemClick it starts the activity.

How can I make it so that instead of starting the associated app, it adds them from my custom dialog to the fragment which holds the button that launches the dialog, along with the apps name? Aka making a shortcut to a different app.

What I assume to be the relevant bit is my ItemClick:

```
    @Override
public void onGridItemClick(GridView g, View v, int position, long id) {
    AppModel app = (AppModel) getGridAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (app != null) {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.getApplicationPackageName());

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, how am I able to make the app remember what's been added? I don't want the user to have to re-add whatever it added the last time the app was launched.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a single activity from which you call the dialog, this solution might work.

Create **static** variables for the *package* of the selected app in your activity, and one more for the *app name*:

```
public static string app_pkg = null;
public static string app_name = null;
```

Create a button in your activity that is to show the *text of the selected app* and launch it when the user clicks the button. Make your button for app click **static** in the same way. Initially, *hide* that button from view.

Then use,

```
   @Override
public void onGridItemClick(GridView g, View v, int position, long id) {
AppModel app = (AppModel) getGridAdapter().getItem(position); 
 if (app != null) {

  ActivityName.app_pkg = app.getApplicationPackageName().toString();
  ActivityName.app_name = app.getApplicationName().toString(); //not sure about this statement for the class AppModel ( it will be something similar to this, just check 
  ActivityName.button_name.setText(ActivityName.app_name); //Set the button with selected app name here
  // unhide your button here
   //dismiss your grid here
}  

   }
}
```

And in your activity, in the onClick method of that button,launch the intent

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 if (!app_pkg.equals(null)) {
    Intent lock = new Intent(getActivity(),app_pkg);

    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

 }

    });
```

**Note:** This is not advisable when you have multiple activities, since static variables may cause memory leakage, since they won't be collected normally by the garbage collector and exceptions may arise when the activity to which that static variable belongs to, is destroyed.

But since you have a very simple flow and just three such variables, this should work fine.

Comment: I feel like I can't thank you enough for being willing to help educate me on this matter.

If I understand correctly, app_pkg stores the applications name as a string, then sets the text on the button as the applications name. Correct? Upon onClick it will launch said app. 

The problem I'd face then is that it would still only be one single button. I'd like to populate my fragment with as many apps the user adds as possible in a new gridview. 

Correct about simplicity. One FragmentActivity with several dynamic fragments with custom onClick methods to interact from Fragment -> Activity.

Comment: app_pkg will store the *package name* of the app, not *app-name*. Package name is something which is more consistent across different versions of the same app, so in case you would like to make use of a parameter which is constant for a long time, package name fits the bill. I am editing my answer. You can similarly get the app name itself for setting the button name. But you would still require the *package name* of the app for launching it thru intent.

Comment: So you are saying that suppose, user clicks more than one option in the gridview, it should pop up as separate buttons in your activity?

Comment: Preferrably, but it's not a must. Just a convenience thing. As I said in your earlier answer in the comments, it should behave just like how a launcher makes shortcuts. E.g Apex Launcher, you press and hold to get a dialog which shows a listview, with one of them being "Shortcuts". Press it and it starts a new Activity giving you a list of installed apps. Select one and it adds to your homescreen. I've emailed the Vogella.com team regarding their SQLite example, but they do warn they don't have time to help with such questions.

Comment: This is just not very well documented. I'm figuring most developers that create launchers (and there are many!) steal their work from others (i.e CyanogenMod's Trebuchet launcher). Which hurts new developers like me who wants to use a function that launchers perform. If this gets resolved, I hope this helps other beginners looking for the same problem.

Comment: You can *dynamically* add buttons as per your requirement. Many examples here in SO. And there are events and listeners for *longpress* available, just like for normal click.